# Problems with chrome.proxy API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to use the chrome proxy api but i keep getting this error for some reason. I thought i was doing everything right but i guess not :/

here is my code...

```
var proxy_type;
var proxy_port;
var proxy_ip;
chrome.storage.sync.get(['proxy_type', 'proxy_port', 'proxy_ip', 'proxy'], function(items) {
    console.log('Settings retrieved', Object.values(items));
    proxy_type = items.proxy_type; //this is equal to socks5
    proxy_ip = items.proxy_ip; //this is equal to 66.78.44.221
    proxy_port = parseInt(items.proxy_port); //this is equal to 58124
});
var config = {
  mode: "fixed_servers",
  rules: {
    singleProxy: {
      scheme: proxy_type,
      host: proxy_ip,
      port:proxy_port
    },
    bypassList: ["foobar.com"]
  }
};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");  
    if (request.greeting == "connect"){
        console.log('setting proxy');
        console.log(proxy_ip); //shows 66.78.44.221 in the log...
        chrome.proxy.settings.set(
          {value: config, scope: 'regular'},
          function() {});
    }
  });
```

Whenever i run this code though, i get the error: `Error in event handler for runtime.onMessage: Error: Invalid value for argument 1. Property 'value.rules.singleProxy.host': Property is required.`

If i set the values of scheme, host, and port by just typing the values in instead of using a variable it works.

So why am i getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the host field in the config may be undefined.  Since the `chrome.storage.sync.get` is asynchronous, I expect that config object is constructed before the proxy parameters are defined.

You could construct config in the callback and check that it is defined in the message handler:

```
var config;

chrome.storage.sync.get(['proxy_type', 'proxy_port', 'proxy_ip', 'proxy'], function(items) {
    console.log('Settings retrieved', Object.values(items));
    config = {
      mode: "fixed_servers",
      rules: {
        singleProxy: {
          scheme: items.proxy_type,
          host: items.proxy_ip,
          port: parseInt(items.proxy_port)
        },
        bypassList: ["foobar.com"]
      }
    };
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (!config) {
        console.log('proxy config not defined');
        return;
    }
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");  
    if (request.greeting == "connect"){
        console.log('setting proxy');
        console.log(config); //shows 66.78.44.221 in the log...
        chrome.proxy.settings.set(
          {value: config, scope: 'regular'},
          function() {});
    }
});
```